# Unable to connect to Windows Ad-Hoc from 11.10

Tags: 11.10, wireless, windows-7, broadcom, adhoc

I am a newbie to Ubuntu, and loving it except for this AdHoc issue which has been bugging me for a month. I have found numerous posts on the issue with no real solutions, so let me be a bit more specific regarding the issue, and hopefully someone can help me out.

I have a Broadcom Driver on a Dell Inspiron and the Wifi works great. The AdHoc works on a parallel installation of Windows 7, so that should mean the card supports AdHoc. My friends laptop running 11.10 is able to connect to the network via Adhoc with no issues, hence the network is setup right.
Of the many things i have tried so far, I got the **ndiswrapper**, tried all possible configurations (manual configuration) in network manager, even tried the **wicd** manager

The latest breakthrough was when I tried **sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc**

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
```

so i tried **iwconfig wlan0** and got

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

So the Mode is forced to ***Managed*** instead of ***Ad-Hoc***

So, where do I go from here?

Additional Information:

The output for **sudo lshw -C network** is

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 70:f1:a1:89:e7:1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.0.0-17-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:f0500000-f0503fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Atheros Communications
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c1
       serial: b8:ac:6f:65:e4:3e
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:43 memory:f0400000-f043ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have upgraded to 12.04 Precise Pangolin and it is now working great. Haven't been able to spot the initial issue, but with this upgrade, it dosen't matter now.

Answer (score 1):

Create ad-hoc network in ubuntu using network manager and than check in ubuntu it self. whether its running fine. and then go to windows.

you can take help of

[Why can't other machines connect to my ad-hoc wireless network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128422/about-ad-hoc-network)