# Why can't other machines connect to my ad-hoc wireless network?

Tags: network-manager, adhoc

I created ad hoc network in network manager and set static IP address. When I am going to connect with other pc, it's not connecting with that.

I followed this link on Help Ubuntu: [Wifi Docs/Ad hoc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Adhoc)

1. Right-mouse click the NetworkManager icon (top right)
2. Select "Edit Connections"
3. Click the "Wireless" tab
4. Click "Add" to edit a new wireless connection
5. On the wireless dialogue give the connection a name, e.g "Mochudi".

   - SSID: "Mochudi". The SSID will appear on the NetworkManager of your other Peers
   - Mode: Ad Hoc
   - BSSID: leave blank
   - MAC Address: leave blank
   - MTU: leave as automatic
6. Click "Apply"
7. Click "Close"

If fixed IP addresses are required edit the IPv4 Settings Tab before closing NetworkManager above:

...as above then...

6a. Click "IPv4 Settings Tab"

```
* Select Method "Manual"
* Under Addresses click Add
* Type your Address: 10.42.43.1
* Type the Netmask: 255.255.255.0
*

  Gateway: leave blank or 0.0.0.0
```

6b. Click "Apply"

7. Click "Close"

Answer (score 2):

in wpa_supplicant.conf file....

```
ap_scan=2
network={
ssid="gui"
key_mgmt=NONE
mode=1
 }
```

Can connect with non protected ad-hoc network using wpa_supplicant.

using this command....

```
wpa_supplicant -D **driver name** - i **interface name** -c **configuration file path** -dd
```

eg:

```
wpa_supplicant -Dwext - iwlan0 -c /home/xyz/Desktop/wpa_supplicant.conf  -dd
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are connecting windows pc's to the ubuntu ad-hoc network, if you set the ip address to 169.254.x.x and sub net mask to 255.255.0.0 the the pc windows machine will automatically connect to the ad-hoc netework. otherwise you have to setup all the individual pc's with their own static IP's.

Comment: i am using ubuntu as a pc to connect and using wpa_supplicant for establish the connection. But its not happaning... any help